# I'm having trouble submitting form data to an email

Tags: php, email

I have the following code in a form on my site:

```
<form method="post" name="myemailform" action="js/formtoemail.php" id="contactform">
    <p><label>Name</label><input name="name" type="text" /></p>
    <p><label>Email</label><input name="email" type="text" /></p>
    <p><label>Message </label><textarea name="message" cols="1" rows="7"> </textarea></p>
    <p class="a-center"><a onclick="$('#contactform').hide();$('#success-msg').show();" class="button medium lightblue"><span><span>Submit</span></span></a></p>
</form>
```

This is supposed to just pass the name, email and message to the .php file so the data can be emailed and then display a success message.

It doesn't seem to email however.  The php is as follows:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$email_from = 'email@email.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from $visitor_email with the user $name.\n".  "Here is the message:\n $message".
$to = "user@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes, the forced "From" setting in the header will cause the email to be blocked by ISP. Try commenting out the $headers assignments and see if it sends.  (Note that Reply-To is often okay but try first with `$headers='';`)

Comment: Are you running off localhost or a live server? If it's localhost, you will need to set up your configuration to allow it.

Comment: You should use AJAX, unless you want the page to flash, change or you want the form action to go somewhere else. Also, use `"\r\n"` everywhere you have `"\n"`. And you need a `content-type: text/html`, or something.